# Undefined index when posting from Ajax to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Hoping someone can spot the issue here, I have been at it for hours.

I have a simple form

```
    <div class="ibox-content">

First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">

<button class="btn btn-white" onclick="ajax_post();" type="submit">Test</button>
                       </div>
```

Which calls a very simple php file

```
<?php 
echo $_POST['first_name'];
echo $_POST['last_name'];
?>
```

Via an Ajax function

```
function ajax_post(){
// Create our XMLHttpRequest object
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
var url = "result.php";
var fn = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
var ln = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
var vars = "first_name="+fn+"&last_name="+ln;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

I keep getting "Undefined index" for each var back from the php file.
Checking fiddler and wireshark, I can see the variables being posted.

For testing I gave the form a post action and I can see the php respond correctly.

Please help

Comment: You forgot the `name` attributes for your form inputs.

Comment: added ... no change though

Comment: Simplified for form as above now. Still the same

Comment: Your code shows that your var names are not the same as the form names: firstname  first_name

Comment: vars sets the variable name to first_name , which holds the value of firstname. I have changed it to be all the same ... no change

Answer (score 0):

If you try `var_dump($_POST)`, you will notice that the names of the form fields correspond with the `$_POST` array. so if you keep them the same, your code should work.

[edit]
Looking again at your JavaScript, it seems while you read the values of your input fields and concatenate them and store in your `vars` variable, you are not doing anything with them after that, especially you are not posting them to your PHP file.

Comment: var_dump shows an empty array, which suggests the php file is not receiving anything. I can see post data in firebug though

Comment: You can see the post as "hr.send(vars);"

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it, the issue was my url was defined as result.php ... I was using a htaccess though that looked after file extentions, changed the url to result and it worked. So many hours wasted!!!